# Promise waits to get resolve without return

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

My understanding of the async handling in nodejs/javascript is that if an async call is handled in a function it must return a promise or accept a callback for chaining as well as for waiting for the async call to get complete.

But I just find out it does not, as the following code works and wait for all the promises to get completed

```js
function handlePromise() {
  Promise.resolve('Hello Async').then(data => {
    Promise.resolve('Hello Async 2').then(data => {
      return delay(3000).then(() => console.log(data));
    });
    return delay(2000).then(() => console.log(data));
  });

  Promise.resolve('hello').then(data => console.log(data))
};

function delay(time) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, time))
}

function handlePromise2() {
  handlePromise()
};

handlePromise2();
```

It should work when I return the promises up to the end.

```js
function handlePromise() {
 return Promise.resolve('Hello Async').then(data => {
  return Promise.resolve('Hello Async 2').then(data => {
   return delay(3000).then(() => console.log(data));
  });
 }).then(() => {
  return Promise.resolve('hello').then(data => console.log(data))
 }).then(() => {
  return Promise.resolve('hello').then(data => console.log(data))
 });

};

function delay(time) {
 return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, time))
}

function handlePromise2() {
 return handlePromise()
};

handlePromise2();
```

Same works with the callbacks also

```
const fs = require('fs')
function handlePromise() {
    delay();
    console.log('sync')
};

function delay() {
    fs.writeFile('data.txt', 'Hello Async', () => console.log('done'));
}

handlePromise();
```

So what's I am missing out here?

If just calling a then with the promise resolves the promise then whats the point of async/await if I dont need the resolved value?

Comment: Use async/await or call `fs.writeFileSync`. `delay()` below is still an asynchronous function.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you state it clearly?

Comment: @MatJ updated the question

Comment: @Shubham the problem is not that it does not work, the problem is it works and the question is how and why?

Comment: The question is not clear. You have 3 completely different pieces of code doing different things. It is not clear what you are referring to as "code works and wait for all the promises to get completed". Options 1 and 3 might seem "work" because of handrafted timers.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko it works with the I/O operations as well.

Comment: @AZ_ Well it is just not clear what do you mean by "works"? And why it surprises you :).

Comment: If you mean that node process is not terminated even though "your code" does not care about the result then it wont until there are scheduled tasks (timers or I/O). BTW you could unref timer to make node ignore one before exit. Your first example would exit node if you do `resolve => setTimeout(resolve, time).unref()`

Comment: Even you can also use async waterfall() for this operation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If i understand your question right, you're saying that the first snippet should not work because it's not returning the promises and you're asking why is it working.

Short answer: It's not *really* working, `handlePromise2()` finished and returned without waiting on the promises to get resolved or rejected.

Long answer: It's like you going to the bakery and asking for a bread, but instead of waiting in line after asking for it you leave, the bread still gets baked but then it gets thrown away because the client (In our case that's `handlePromise2`) made the call and assumed that the work is finished, after all its scope was to just call that function.

Promises are used so that the client that's calling the function knows to expect something, so after you'd ask for the bread you'd wait for it to be finished, and that's called a **promise** it's not the actual value (aka bread) but a promise of a value.
That's what you're doing in the second snippet.

And now poor `handlePromise()` doesn't know what to do with the food [image]

Comment: you understood it right if it does not work how I am still getting the output on the console, why event loop still is waiting. I already added i dont care about the resolved values but just the completion.
so when I add an I/O operation like writing into a file with an async call, but not waiting for it, still it completes then what's the different sync and async methods?

Comment: @AZ_ because the thread is still alive, the app didn't exit after `handlePromise2()` ended

Comment: so the process will not terminate until there are events in event queue?

Comment: Nope, JS does not terminate on its own until the server terminates it so it depends on what you're running it on, i.e. browser, node...etc